# Page is completely valid HTML5, is blank in IE11

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer-11

I'm completely baffled by the behavior of IE 11 here. My page is completely "valid" HTML5 but IE 11 completely balks at rendering the page... any ideas?

http://sidearmstats.com/maui/mbball/

Comment: Which OS are you using ? I'm on Windows 8.1 and your page renders just fine using IE 11 (11.0.9600.16384)

Comment: @sh1rts mine is Win 8.1 11.0.9600.16438 (11.0.1) as well. It works now.. I must've gotten an update at some point

Comment: Good to hear ! Nice looking site, keep at it :)